# How to transfer image & files to server using UDP/TCP Client Programm in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, tcp, udp

[image]

```
 - (IBAction)sendBuf:(id)sender
   {
    _imageVw.image=nil;

    if ([[bufOut text] length] > 0)
    {
        NSString *requestStr = [bufOut text];
        NSData *requestData = [requestStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [asyncSocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];//Writing to stream data
//        [asyncUDPSocket sendData:requestData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:1];
        [self debugPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sent:  \n%@",requestStr]];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

        _imageVw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];

    }
    [self startRead];
}
```

I have done this code for sending text & image . Text was sending successfully but image was not sending properly.I have done this demo from this [here](https://github.com/ignazioc/SimpleAsyncSocketExample). I am unable to find where was the issue ? And the server was running in c# .net. It will handle both tcp & udp. In server side data is getting like above image.

Comment: Did the server get the data ? How does it distinguish which one is text or image ? How does it tell whether the image data is finished. By the way I think tcp is better.

Comment: Yes Data is getting like in image above .

Comment: Text is getting in server is great. Problem was with image.

Comment: How do you know the image is failed. Did the server save the image to file ?

Comment: No while debugging the data is represented as above screen shot. But see there is start with PNG. that is type of image.

Comment: You're using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, so it is PNG format though the source file is a jpeg file. A easy way to know if the image was sent successfully is to say the data to a file and open it with some image viewers.

Comment: So I need to check with png image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81957/discussion-between-karthik-m-and-kudocc).

Comment: Sorry I'm busy with working at that time. I think the server has received the image data. But I think you should also tell the server when you finished sending or the server don't know when to stop. I recommend you to use TCP and before send the image data or the text, you should send fix-length byte (for example 4 byte) to indicate how large the data that you will send afterwards is. So when the server receive the first 4 byte, they can calculate the total data length, after the length of data it received reaches the total length, it can interpret the data.

Comment: Right now I am using TCP but same problem occuring.

Comment: Sorry, but what problem, the server has already received the data.

Comment: Did you seen in my post there is one image.

Comment: Yes, I did. But the image data isn't readable, the data you get is reasonable.

Comment: Yeah that type of data is came in server .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81968/discussion-between-karthik-m-and-kudocc).